# Is there maven archetypes for App Engine + Spring

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, gwt, maven

Is there any maven archectypes for:

- GWT + Spring
- Spring + AppEngine
- GWT + Spring + AppEngine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the googling for you and found:

- [gwt-spring-archetype](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-archetype/)
- [gae-mvn-archetype](http://code.google.com/p/gae-mvn-archetype/) - Maven Archetype for GAE/J project
- [gae-archetype-gwt](https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin) - GWT based example